# Socket.IO Emit Function Only Works Once in React Native

Tags: react-native, websocket, socket.io

I want to develop a chat application using React Native (EXPO) and Socket.IO, but I'm facing an issue. On the React Native side, I can successfully connect to the server, but I can only send an event to the server once, and then it stops working without any error. When I console.log the Socket object, everything seems normal, but the emit function only works once. There doesn't seem to be any issue on the server side because I tested it using Postman, and everything worked fine. Apart from the emit function, there don't appear to be any other problems on the client side. When I send an event from the server to the client, I can receive it without any issues. I'm using the latest version of Socket.IO on both the client and server sides.

Here is the code:

```
import io, { Socket } from "socket.io-client";
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";

let socket: Socket;
export async function initializeSocket() {
  const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("token");
  socket = io(process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL as string, {
    query: { token },
    transports: ["websocket"],
    autoConnect: true,
    retries: 10,
    reconnectionAttempts: 10,
    reconnectionDelay: 5000,
  });
}

export function getSocket() {
  return socket;
}

initializeSocket();
```

Main.tsx

```
import { getSocket } from "../lib/socket";

export default function Main() {
  const socket = getSocket();

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      Toast.show({
        type: ALERT_TYPE.SUCCESS,
        title: "Message",
        textBody: "Socket connection successful.",
      });
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      Toast.show({
        type: ALERT_TYPE.DANGER,
        title: "Error",
        textBody:
          "Disconnected from the server.",
      });
    });

    socket.on("connect_error", () => {
      Toast.show({
        type: ALERT_TYPE.DANGER,
        title: "Error",
        textBody:
          "Connection to the server failed.",
      });
    });
    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, [socket]);

  return (...)

}
```

Students.tsx

```
import { getSocket } from "../lib/socket";
export default function Students() {
  const socket = getSocket();
  const [nearbyUsers, setNearbyUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (data: any) => {
      setNearbyUsers(data);
    };

    socket.on("nearbyUsers", listener);

    return () => {
      socket.off("nearbyUsers", listener);
    };
  }, [socket]);

  return (
    <>
      <Appbar.Header>
        <Appbar.Content title={`Students (${nearbyUsers.length})`} />
      </Appbar.Header>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          socket.emit("nearbyUsers");
        }}
      >
        update
      </Button>
    </>
)
```

I'm using socket.io version 4.7.2 both client and server side.